# Call REST API & render tabs React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rest

I want to render Material UI tabs depending on the API. I have created a separate component for tabs and I call it on my page. I have made a local array but now I want to render as per the API data. Following is my codebase.

Tab component

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import PhoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Phone";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import PersonPinIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PersonPin";
import HelpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Help";
import ShoppingBasket from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingBasket";
import ThumbDown from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbDown";
import ThumbUp from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { DateRangeSharp } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { List, ListItem, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";

const DATES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    day: "WED",
    date: 19,
    theater: [{ tname: "vista", price: 450 }, { tname: "liberty", price: 550 }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    day: "THU",
    date: 20,
    theater: [{ tname: "PVR" }, { tname: "CCC" }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    day: "FRI",
    date: 21,
    theater: [{ tname: "vista" }, { tname: "liberty" }]
  },
  { id: 4, day: "SAT", date: 22 },
  { id: 5, day: "SUN", date: 23 },
  { id: 6, day: "MON", date: 24, theater: [{ tname: "vista" }, { tname: "liberty" }] },
  { id: 7, day: "TUE", date: 25 },
  { id: 8, day: "WED", date: 26 }
];

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-force-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));

export default function ScrollableTabsButtonForce() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue ] = React.useState(0);
  


  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar
        position="static"
        style={{ background: "#333545", minHeight: 60 }}
      >
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="on"
          indicatorColor="secondary"
          textColor="primary"
          aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
          style={{ minHeight: 60 }}
          wrapped
        >
          {DATES.map((showtdates) => {
            return (
              <Tab
                label={showtdates.date + " " + showtdates.day}
                {...a11yProps(0)}
                style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 20, minHeight: 60 }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {/* map over dates and create TabPanel */}

      {DATES.map((date, idx) => {
        // check if theater property exists and create a list of theaters as an example
        const theaters = date.hasOwnProperty("theater")
          ? date.theater.map((theater) => (
              <ListItem>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={theater.tname}
                  secondary={theater.price}
                />
              </ListItem>
            ))
          : null;

        return (
          <TabPanel value={value} index={idx}>
            <List>{theaters}</List>
          </TabPanel>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

following is my main page where I need to render the Tab

```
export class movieBooking extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      VenuesDates: [],
      dataLoaded: false,
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
        let movieInfo = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
        console.log(movieInfo.movieid) 
        this.setState(movieInfo)
        console.log(movieInfo.name) 
     
    movieName = movieInfo

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
    };
    fetch(`http://sandbox-api.tickets.lk/v1/movie/${movieName.movieid}/showtime`, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((VenuesShowDates) => {
          console.log(VenuesShowDates.data.venueDateShowtime)
          this.setState({ 
            VenuesDates: VenuesShowDates.data.venueDateShowtime,
            dataLoaded: true,
           })
        }).catch(console.log);
        console.log(movieName.movieid)
           
      }
    
    
    render() {
        return (
<div>
{/* here i want to render the tab */}
</div>
```

this is it will shows
[image: tab list]
Looking up for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import your tabs component into your movie booking component, then just use it inside your div tag.  You'll need to pass your api response data to the tabs component as a prop.  Then use the response prop inside your tabs component.